# Create new onlineMeeting results in AuthenticationError

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, bubble.io

After authentication by authorization (not delegation), I got this error trying to [create an onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings) knowing that I have correctly configured the permissions.

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings`

```json
{
   "startDateTime": "2023-07-12T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
   "endDateTime": "2023-07-12T15:00:34.2464912-7:00",
   "subject": "User Token Meeting"
}
```

Comment: Please post the code and the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you grant `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All` to your application? See azure portal (app registrations)
- Did you use the correct scope in your authentication?
- Did you add the bearer token to you header in postman?
- Did you check if the bearer token has the correct scope? (decode the json web token to check)